# Data Annotation for Dollar Currency and Date is not Working Properly in Asp.net MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations, .net-6.0

Here, I am using Data Annotation for Showing Currency in Dollar but Dollar sign is not showing.

Also I want to show only Date. But after taking the  input Its shows the time also. How to fix it?

My model is given below-

```
public class BTBPending
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("VALUE")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public int Value { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DisplayName("SHIP. DATE")]
        public DateTime ShipDate { get; set; }
}
```

My Table View is given below-

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm align-middle m-0" id="header">
           <tr class="table-info m-0" style="text-align:center">                    
                        <th>Value</th>
                        <th>Ship.Date</th>
           </tr>
       @foreach (var BTBPending in Model)
                            {
                                <tr class="m-0"> 
                                    <td style="text-align:right">@BTBPending.Value</td>
                                    <td>@BTBPending.ShipDate</td> 
                                </tr>
                            }
</table>
```

Comment: "Doller" is dollar?

Comment: Where are you showing it? I don't see any code related to displaying this values to user.

Comment: I Updated My table view

Comment: Your code is just printing the property value. `DisplayFormat` is used when using data binding or `Html.DisplayFor` and `DisplayForModel`

Comment: So how can i solve this issue?